# Mass astar pathfinding

Tags: javascript, html, path-finding, a-star

I'm trying to create a tower defence game in Javascript.

It's all going well apart from the pathfinding..

I'm using the astar code from this website: http://www.briangrinstead.com/blog/astar-search-algorithm-in-javascript which uses a binary heap (which I believe is fairly optimal)

The problem i'm having is I want to allow people to block the path of the "attackers". This means that each "attacker" needs to be able to find its way to the exit on its own (as someone could just cut off a single "attacker" and it would need to find its own way to the exit). Now 5/6 attackers can pathfind at any one time with no issue. But say the path is blocked for 10+ attackers, all 10 of them will need to fire its pathfinding script at the same time which just drops the FPS to about 1/2 per sec.

This must be a common problem for anyone who has a lot of entities pathfinding at anyone time, so I imagine there must be a better way than my approach.

So my question is: What is the best way to implement mass pathfinding algorithm to multiple "bots" in the most efficient way.

Thanks,

James

Comment: It looks like the `findGraphNode` in that code takes linear-time, while it should be taking constant time (with a hash table), so that implementation is far from optimal.

Comment: I'll take look see if I can speed it up a little bit. But i think even with more efficient path finding I'll still end up with the slow framerates if I try and pathfind the bots.. I'm starting to think my best bet is actually pathfinding the whole map once per frame then setting a direction on each passable block for the bots to follow..

Comment: @james if this is anything like most tower defense, with roughly a screen worth of map and no complex collisons (i.e. bots don't collide with each other or other moving objects, or you handle this separately) then yes I would think calculating paths for the entire map would be best. In fact, you should probably not even have to recalculate the entire map every frame. If you are careful in building an algorithm, you should be able to determine which nodes are affected by a user change, and recalculate only 'upstream' from those nodes. Sounds interesting!

Comment: @james You can probably use Dijkstra's algorithm as a rough starting point. As a side note, algorithmic path-finding can be slightly boring and (depending on the game) unrealistic. You might consider alternatives, such as steering behaviors, that are not only fast but do not guarantee perfect paths. If done correctly, this can give a bit more "life" to your bots, but whether that is desirable is up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *Anti-objects*, this is the only way to get cheap pathfinding, afaik : 
http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~ralex/papers/PDF/OOPSLA06antiobjects.pdf

Anti-object basically mean that instead of bots having individual ai, you will have one "swarm ai", which is bound to your game map.

---

p.s.: Here is another link about pathfinding in general (possibly the best online reference available):
http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/index.html

Comment: thanks for the resource i'll take a look a little later. Though just from what you have said it does seem like it makes more sense to pathfind the whole map and maybe set a direction on each "block" that the bots follow.. hmmm

Answer (score 0):

Just cache the result.

Store the path as the value in a hash table (object), give each node a UUID, concatenate the UUIDs to form a unique hash table key and insert the path into it.

When you retrieve the path back out of the hash table, walk the path, and see if it's still valid, if not, recalculate and insert the new one back in.

There are many optimization that you can do :)

Like c69 said swarm AI or hive mind come to mind :P